# CakePHP combining Recursive and Group

Tags: cakephp, recursive-query

I have recursive set to Two on my find query, this is great and returns all the results i want, but i need to group by Day on the results that are Teo levels deep in the recursive query.

This is what i have: `Project->Track->Lapse`. But i need to group by Day on the Track results, how can i do this?

```
$project = $this->Project->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
                'Project.id' => $id,
                'Project.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
    ),
    'recursive' => 2
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, Cake's ORM tend to be very disappointing for anything beyond the trivial. Here's is what I would do to find a solution:

1. First of all, enable debug level 2 and take a look at the queries Cake is generating. That will depend on the types of the associations you have in place. If it's generating a single query for your `find()`, you're lucky! Just add a 'group' key to the find options array, and it's done.
2. Since Cake is probably generating more than one query, there are two possible solutions:

   a) Try [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable). If you are able to manipulate its options to force Cake to build a single query with the proper `JOIN`s, you are ready to just add the 'group' options to the find. However, I have often been frustrated trying that, and resorted to the following option.

   b) Manually inform Cake about the `JOIN`s it will have to use in order to be able to group the results. You can do that by first unbinding all associated models ([this](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/cornernote/2006/12/10/unbindall) might be useful), then using the ['joins' option](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/nate/2009/01/21/quick-tip-doing-ad-hoc-joins-in-model-find) to force the joins. Then you can add the 'group' option to the find.

I actually use option 2b quite frequently, not only when I have to group results, but also to filter by associated models.