# PHP Group By Day

Tags: php

Given this array:

```
    array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Project"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["user_id"]=>
      string(2) "21"
      ["customer_id"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["name"]=>
      string(15) "WordPress Theme"
      ["created"]=>
      string(19) "2011-09-26 21:30:38"
    }
    ["Track"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(8) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "7"
        ["user_id"]=>
        string(2) "21"
        ["project"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["customer"]=>
        string(1) "4"
        ["title"]=>
        string(7) "Backend"
        ["notes"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["created"]=>
        string(19) "2011-09-28 22:21:22"
        ["Lapse"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          array(5) {
            ["id"]=>
            string(1) "4"
            ["track_id"]=>
            string(1) "7"
            ["start"]=>
            string(19) "2011-09-28 22:22:21"
            ["stop"]=>
            string(19) "2011-09-28 22:22:30"
            ["created"]=>
            string(19) "2011-09-28 22:22:21"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(5) {
            ["id"]=>
            string(1) "3"
            ["track_id"]=>
            string(1) "7"
            ["start"]=>
            string(19) "2011-09-28 22:22:07"
            ["stop"]=>
            string(19) "2011-09-28 22:22:12"
            ["created"]=>
            string(19) "2011-09-28 22:22:07"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How would i group by Day in the Lapse Array with PHP? This may have been easier to do directly with MySQL but i'm using CakePHP's recursive function and i cant figure out how to use Group By with that!

Comment: "This may have been easier to do directly with MySQL but i'm using CakePHP's recursive function and i cant figure out how to use Group By with that!" --- you cannot do that with php either ;-P

Comment: I feared. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: I just answered [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590402/cakephp-combining-recursive-and-group) on CakePHP + GROUP + Associations, you should take a look. *EDIT* Just noticed the other question is also yours! :)

Comment: maybe you should look for custom query support in CakePHP?

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = array();

function extractByDates($arr) {
  foreach ($arr as $key => $v)
    if (is_array($v))
      function extractByDates($v);
    else if ($key == 'created')
      $list[$v] = $v;
}

extractByDates($yourGivenArray);
```

I not tested!